# ubuntu: What can be the maximum receive buffer size for UDP

Tags: ubuntu

I am receiving some data on UDP/Multicast lines. The ram on the machine is 32G and the UDP receive buffer size is around 8MB, but still I am facing packet drops. So I want to increase the receive buffer size as large as possible. Are there any restriction on the maximum size of the buffer